# Java HttpHandler related issue

Tags: java, wildfly, undertow

I am having a HttpHandler like below.

```
@Override
    public void handleRequest(HttpServerExchange exchange) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("In the handler");

        SecurityContext securityContext = exchange.getSecurityContext();
        if(securityContext != null){
            if(securityContext.isAuthenticated()){
                if(somechecks() ) {
                    //redirect to login error page
                }
                }
            }
        }

        next.handleRequest(exchange);
    }
```

How can i redirect to the error page from the handler ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public static void redirectTo(HttpServerExchange exchange, String uri) {
    exchange.getResponseHeaders().add(HttpString.tryFromString("Location"), uri);
    exchange.setStatusCode(StatusCodes.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
    exchange.getResponseSender().close();
}
```

Comment: You might want to explain where to put in code and to `return` afterwards -  otherwise access to already closed Response might occur and create unneeded errors.

Comment: Its throwing the below exception .

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange.setStatusCode(I)Lio/undertow/server/HttpServerExchange;

Comment: I have tested it with undertow 1.3.9.Final version. If it compiles successfully but get exception at runtime. Than You may have different version in the runtime. Can you show me the actual code and stacktrace

Comment: How can i find the version of undertow on my wildfly ?

Comment: You can update your wildfly version from here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wildfly/wildfly-undertow/9.0.0.Final

Answer (score 0):

for Handlers redirection I use, the RedirectHandelr :

```
RedirectHandler redirectHandler = new RedirectHandler("yourErrorPageURL");
redirectHandler.handleRequest(exchange);
```